# Need to split lists using Delimite operation in SWI-prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying my hands on prolog.

I want to do following operation:

Suppose, I have a `list = [7/5,6/4,5/4,6/3]`

And I want to split it in two lists:

list 1 will contain `[7,6,5,6]` 
list 2 will contain `[5,4,4,3]`

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: `XYs = [7/5,6/4,5/4,6/3], maplist(\ (X/Y)^X^Y^true, XYs, Xs, Ys).` using `library(lambda)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find library(lambda) so I don't know how that works---where is this library? Why don't you say which Prolog implementation you use? It is maybe more easy to help then?

This is how it can be done otherwise with textbook Prolog:

```
split_fractions([], [], []).
split_fractions([X/Y|XYs], [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
    split_fractions(XYs, Xs, Ys).
```

This just says that if the list is empty, the two lists are empty; and if the list has a `X/Y` at head, then other lists have `X` and `Y` at heads, and same for rest of lists.

Or you can use `maplist` like @lurker says:

```
split_fractions(XYs, Xs, Ys) :-
    maplist(frac_num_den, XYs, Xs, Ys).

frac_num_den(X/Y, X, Y).
```

And if you find library(lambda) in this link:

http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl

You can save this file and then if you start `swipl` in the same directory as `lambda.pl`you can write:

```
?- use_module(lambda).
true.

%%                                !!!
?- XYs = [a/1, b/2, c/3], maplist(\ (X/Y)^X^Y^true, XYs, Xs, Ys).
XYs = [a/1, b/2, c/3],
Xs = [a, b, c],
Ys = [1, 2, 3].
```

I have not read the documentation but it seems the empty space I marked with !!! is significant.

From here:

http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord.html

It seems "documentation" is on that link and in the lambda.pl file. I could not find fast where it explains why the whitespace must be there.

And because I don't want to leave anyone out, here is another lambda library for SWI that I found, this one is available directly:

```
?- use_module(library(yall)).
true.

?- maplist([X/Y, X, Y]>>true, [a/1, b/2, c/3], Xs, Ys).
Xs = [a, b, c],
Ys = [1, 2, 3].
```

but maybe it is much better without lambda altogether.

Comment: You can still use `maplist/3` without the lambda. Define `frac_num_den(X/Y, X, Y).` then use `maplist(frac_num_den, Fractions, Numerators, Denominators).`

Comment: @lurker: thank you for the suggestion! yes, `maplist/3` is in GNU Prolog and SWI at least. Edited the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @lurker OK, I found a library(lambda) but I don't know how it works with GNU Prolog. But it works with SWI-Prolog, I put in my answer for completeness.

Comment: The library specific to SWI Prolog. The `maplist` solution I showed works in both GNU and SWI. The lambda just lets you skip having to define the extra predicate explicitly and essentially put it inline with the `maplist` call.

Comment: @lurker ok, I see, thank you. I thought the library is not specific to SWI Prolog but it needs `use_module` and directives? and I don't know if lambda helps that much because your suggestion `frac_num_den` is a self-documenting name so it is easier to understand.

Comment: A lambda is a nice language feature offered in other languages (*e.g.*, LISP and Ruby have them). SWI thus has the library. It allows you to define simple functional (or in this case, predicate) definitions inline instead of defining them separately, particularly when it's only used in one place. It has its advantages and disadvantages. I'm sure you can find a lot of general information online about lambdas that would explain it in detail.

Comment: @lurker thank you very much for your help. I might know what is lambda, I maybe only attempt to say that with `frac_num_den` as you suggest is good because "fraction numerator denominator" is the relation that it defines, and the name helps to know, or maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
[user]
.

%%  `my:exampl` --  "base case" %%

my:exampl([],[],[])
:-
(
    true
)
.

%%  `my:exampl` --  "recursiv case" %%

my:exampl(__p__,__pq__,__q__)
:-
(
    [__p_a__|__p_z__]           =   __p__   ,
    [__p_a__/__q_a__|__pq_z__]  =   __pq__  ,
    [__q_a__|__q_z__]           =   __q__   ,

    my:exampl(__p_z__,__pq_z__,__q_z__) %
)
.

end_of_file
.


/* ..   showing tht it works in the typical usage   :   */

?- 
|    my:exampl(__p__,[7/5,6/4,5/4,6/3],__q__) 
|    .
__p__ = [7, 6, 5, 6],
__q__ = [5, 4, 4, 3] ;
false.



/* ..   showing tht it works in the REVERSE direction of the typical usage  :   */

?- 
|    my:exampl([7, 6, 5, 6],__pq__,[5, 4, 4, 3])
|    .
__pq__ = [7/5, 6/4, 5/4, 6/3] ;
false.

/* ..   showing tht it is STEADFAST in the typical usage    :   */

?-
my:exampl(__p__,__pq__,__q__) , __pq__ = [7/5,6/4,5/4,6/3]
.
__p__  = [7, 6, 5, 6],
__pq__ = [7/5, 6/4, 5/4, 6/3],
__q__  = [5, 4, 4, 3] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack

/* ..   showing tht it FAILS in the typical usage   :   */

?- 
|    my:exampl([7, 6/*, 5, 6*/],__pq__,[5, 4, 4, 3])
|    .
false.

/* ..   showing tht it provides meaningful answers for the most GENERAL usage   :   */

?-
my:exampl(__p__,__pq__,__r__)
.
__p__ = __pq__, __pq__ = __r__, __r__ = [] ;
__p__ = [_1894],
__pq__ = [_1894/_1908],
__r__ = [_1908] ;
__p__ = [_1894, _1918],
__pq__ = [_1894/_1908, _1918/_1932],
__r__ = [_1908, _1932] ;
__p__ = [_1894, _1918, _1942],
__pq__ = [_1894/_1908, _1918/_1932, _1942/_1956],
__r__ = [_1908, _1932, _1956] ;
__p__ = [_1894, _1918, _1942, _1966],
__pq__ = [_1894/_1908, _1918/_1932, _1942/_1956, _1966/_1980],
__r__ = [_1908, _1932, _1956, _1980] 
Action (h for help) ? abort

% Execution Aborted

/* .. APPENDIX : A solution with maplist does not succeed the 2nd test : */

[user]
.

my:example:maplist(Numerators, Fractions, Denominators)
:-
maplist(frac_num_den, Fractions, Numerators, Denominators)
.

frac_num_den(X/Y, X, Y).

end_of_file .


/* .. testing : */

?- 
|    my:exampl([7, 6, 5, 6],__pq__,[5, 4, 4, 3])
|    .
__pq__ = [7/5, 6/4, 5/4, 6/3] ;
false.

?- 
|    my:exampl:maplist(__p__,[7/5,6/4,5/4,6/3],__q__)
|    .
ERROR: apply:maplist_/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```